# Apache Ignite: What is best practice to fire/emit user defined events in Java?

Tags: java, events, ignite

I want to emit a user defined Ignite event but haven't found any examples or implementations other than the Ignite sources, which uses non-API methods.

Can someone explain how to do this?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading the docs i found a useful hint.

The brief description of `recordLocal(Event evt)`:
[image: Brief description]

After browsing the details i recognised the hint (marked in red)
[image: Detailed description]

So for local events "record" means "store and publish".
It's somehow misleading ... but hey, it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Updated with respect to the latest replies:*

There is a set of predefined `EventTypes` and you can't add a new one or embed a custom logic inside Ignite's internals without recompiling the sources which is too complex and impractical from my point of view.

As an alternative, you can use the [Ignite Messaging](https://ignite.apache.org/features/messaging.html).

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();

IgniteMessaging rmtMsg = ignite.message(ignite.cluster().forRemotes());

// Add listener for ordered messages on all remote nodes.
rmtMsg.remoteListen("MyOrderedTopic", (nodeId, msg) -> {
    System.out.println("Received ordered message [msg=" + msg + ", from=" + nodeId + ']');

    return true; // Return true to continue listening.
});

// Send ordered messages to remote nodes.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    rmtMsg.sendOrdered("MyOrderedTopic", Integer.toString(i), 0);
```

Check [these examples](https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/messaging) and [the documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/messaging).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm afraid that's not what I'm looking for.
I want to emit a user defined event (-extended from EventAdapter class).

Comment: Can you provide an example of a custom message? What you'd like to capture and why messaging or existing events couldn't solve that case?

Comment: The reason why I want to generate a user event is because of the situation that a putAll-call results in EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT events for each entry written to a cache.
To avoid this I want to emit a single event after a successfull putAll().

Comment: Well, to embed a new PUTALL event you need to update the sources and recompile Ignite somehow. I've updated the answer with respect to the latest replies

Comment: Why do you need this PUTALL signal by the way? What's the next logic? Is it just a successful loading indicator or do you need all the updated values?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have found a solution for my problem.
BTW: It's not entirely true that you can't create new EventTypes. It's possible to use your own event ids if you respect the reserved id range (0-1000).